# How do I transfer app data from one an s4 mini to a s5

Tags: applications, data-recovery

Is there a way to transfer my app data  from one phone to another. We've done saving it to a sd card and even downloaded a back app but it only saved the app. When I transfer my games I have to start from scratch again.. is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Applications/Games save the user data like scores, gold amount, ammo etc in `/data` directory. thus you'll need root access on both of your devices to transfer apps with data. if you don't have root access this cannot be done by normal means. if you already have root access then use apps like **Titanium backup** or any other your favorite to backup apps, most of them have facility for rooted users like **Backup app with data**. Then you can transfer the backup to other device and just restore it with same application this should work for normal low-to-mid range games.

**Note**: This can be done with file explorer app also. just find the data directory of your game in `/data` folder copy it to your other device where you want data to be restored. overwrite the directory in other device. kill the app from memory and relaunch it and see if it works. (Remember Root access required for any method)